# Is it possible to use $1 in a regex match?

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating a text parser, that basically looks for the following:

```
{IF SOMETHING} then include this text {ENDIF SOMETHING}
```

I can find that by using the regex:

```
/{IF [A-Z]+}.*{ENDIF [A-Z]}/
```

But that wont help if there are nested conditions. So i was looking to do something more like:

```
/{IF ([A-Z]+)}.*{ENDIF $1}/
```

But that doesn't seem to work - is it possible?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Regex uses \1 instead of $1. For more information, refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) on regex back references.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this other syntax too: `\g{1}` that is useful to avoid confusion with a backreference followed with a literal digit. This syntax allows to use relative references like this:`\g{-1}` *(i.e. the last defined capture group on the left)*

`$1` is only used in a replacement string with `preg_replace`.